# Form lexicographically small string among others by removing exactly one character

Tags: algorithm

E.g. for string *"applea"*, by removing *"p"*, we get *"alea"*, the smallest of other lexicographical strings.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the question. If you want help with coding then please include your own efforts to solve the problem.

Comment: Are you asking how to determine which character to remove from a string to produce the lexicographically earliest result of all the results possible by removing a character?

Comment: We can remove any one character to obtain strings

Comment: But among strings left which is smallest lexicographically stringe

Comment: Every occurence of 1 character? Otherwise I don't get the example

Comment: I am unable to check lexicographically order

Comment: I would guess you are referring to "small" in the context of lexicographical comparison? In which case length of the "filtered string" is not the main factor, but rather the character by character lexicographical value (e.g. ASCII value, if just ASCII characters), starting at the beginning of the string? If so, the lexicographically smallest "filtered" string would always be the the one where we remove the first character which has a smaller valued character following it (or duplicates of it).

Comment: A brute force way (*iff* I understand your question correctly) : create all the different possible strings that can be formed by removing a single character. Then sort the strings lexicographically and pick the first string in the sorted container.

Comment: @jesper can you explain algo or code??

Comment: @Mansi Agarwal - I thought I just explained the (primitive) algorithm. Converting that explanation into code should be trivial.

Comment: What is a *"lexicographical string"*?

Answer (score 2):

Given a string *s* with characters *s*<sub>*i*</sub> for 0 ≤ *i* < *n*, an algorithm to determine *i* such that the string resulting from removing *s*<sub>*i*</sub> is less than or equal to (by lexicographic ordering) the result of removing *s*<sub>*j*</sub> for any *j* is:

1. Set *i* to 0.
2. If *i* = *n*−1, stop. *i* is the result.
3. If *s*<sub>*i*</sub> > *s*<sub>*i+1*</sub>, stop. *i* is the result.
4. Add 1 to *i*.
5. Go to step 2.

Note that *n* must be at least 1, of course.

We can see this works because:

- If *s*<sub>*i*</sub> > *s*<sub>*i+1*</sub>, then removing *s*<sub>*i*</sub> produces a string in which the next character is *s*<sub>*i+1*</sub>, which is less than any string produced by removing a later character, since that leaves *s*<sub>*i*</sub> in place.
- If *s*<sub>*i*</sub> = *s*<sub>*i+1*</sub>, no opportunity for the minimum is lost by choosing to keep *s*<sub>*i*</sub>, as the next character retained necessarily equals *s*<sub>*i*</sub>.
- If *s*<sub>*i*</sub> < *s*<sub>*i+1*</sub>, removing *s*<sub>*i*</sub> would produce a greater string than not removing it, so *s*<sub>*i*</sub> must be retained.

Comment: I must look into it from starting